# what will be the correct sql syntax?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT employee.employ_id, employee.first_name, employee.last_name, works_with.total_sales
FROM employee
JOIN works_with
IN employee.employ_id = (
    SELECT works_with.employ_id
    FROM works_with
    WHERE works_with.total_sales > '100000'
);
```

I need to find the employee's id, first name, last name,amount of total sales whose total sales > 100000 and this is my mysql code.

it is showing that from "IN employee.employ_id....", it's not compiling and showing to find the manual of mariaDB server version.

Then, what will be the correct mysqlcode???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a syntax error in your query.  You are using `IN` and you should be using `ON`.  The way your query works is not quite right, so you need to adjust it to something like:

```
SELECT  e.employ_id,
        e.first_name,
        e.last_name,
        ww.total_sales
  FROM  employee e
    JOIN works_with ww ON ww.employ_id = e.employ_id
  WHERE e.employ_id IN (
                       SELECT  employ_id
                         FROM  works_with
                         WHERE works_with.total_sales > '100000'
                       );
```

However you could look to rewrite your query as it's a bit messy (imo) at the moment:

```
SELECT e.employ_id,
       e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       ww.total_sales
  FROM employee e
    JOIN works_with ww ON e.employ_id = ww.employ_id
  WHERE ww.total_sales > '100000';
```

**Edit following OP comment about multiple rows per employee**

You will be receiving multiple rows because the `JOIN` produces more than one row per employee.  To get the total `SUM` of the `total_sales`, use this modified query:

```
SELECT  e.employ_id,
        e.first_name,
        e.last_name,
        SUM(ww.total_sales) AS total_sales
  FROM  employee e
    JOIN works_with ww ON ww.employ_id = e.employ_id
  WHERE e.employ_id IN (
                       SELECT  employ_id
                         FROM  works_with
                         WHERE works_with.total_sales > '100000'
                       )
  GROUP BY e.employ_id, e.first_name, e.last_name;
```

Comment: but sir, if I use "ON", Then it shows "subquery returns more than 1 rows". So, what will I use???

Comment: @MdAshifUrRahman I have updated the first SQL statement to continue to use `IN`.

Comment: sir, your code has successfully compiled but there are multiple value with same id, name is coming. For collecting highest "total sales" value with the same name and id, I have used "distinct (employee.employ_id, employee.first_name, employee.last_name)" but unfortunately, it's not working.                                            So, how can I get the maximum "total sales" value of the same name and id, sir???

Comment: @MdAshifUrRahman You need to `SUM` the total sales, I'll edit the question to include some extra information